# which git returns /usr/bin/git however there is not such path, how do I reinstall git correctly?

Tags: linux, installation, git, mac

I managed to get git to stop working (Mac OSX Mountain Lion)

When I type "git" it doesn't say command not found, just shows an empty line,

Pressing enter again, exits, and does nothing (yes, I know it's weird)

typing "which git" shows a non existing folder

where do I start troubleshooting this?

I'm new to Mac and Linux (and Git) so don't assume I know anything obvious

Comment: Any clues what you might have been doing when you "managed to get git to stop working"? Uninstalled/deleted anything?

Comment: Not sure what it was, but changing the path to the git version that was installed via the official git osx package did the trick

Comment: If you've managed to solve the problem, please post an answer describing what you did, and then accept it. Welcome to Server Fault!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what it was, but changing the path to the git version that was installed via the official git osx package did the trick (I used `/etc/paths` to change the order, took me a while to find it)